# How to change the background color of NavigationBar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm new to Objective-C, today I tried to change color of my Navigation Bar and this works with this code:

**appDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xf4f4f4)];

    return YES;
}
```

Now I try change specific ViewController navigation bar and this do not work.

**ViewController2.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x363636)];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

When I enter this ViewContoller his Navigation color is `f4f4f4` and when I go other ViewController and come back it changes the color to `363636`.

Why this do not work in first time?
Can somebody explain this to me..

(Sorry About my English, and thank you.)

Comment: please 'accept' the most helpful answer by clicking on the check mark next to each answer.

Answer (score 16):

when you use

```
[UINavigationBar appearance]
```

it changes all of the navbars. in your viewcontroller, just do

```
[self.navigationBar setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x363636)];
```

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x363636)];

this not work..

Comment: it's not setTintColor but setBarTintColor for a navBar

Answer (score 3):

You can implement what Nathanael said in the `-(void) viewDidLoad` method of the view controller. But if you're using the storyboard, you can also select the `navigation item` and change the tint color from the `File inspector` without having to code.

[image]

Comment: I not have tint color in storyboard when I select NavigationItem.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my bad. It's in the `File Inspector`. However it changes the tint color globally. I'll edit my answer to point out the correct inspector. Also I found the following article which has good explanation of customizing the `navigation bar` and `status bar`; you might find it helpful:
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Answer (score 0):

Use tintcolor property of navigation bar to change the color

Answer (score 0):

you can try it, I change in my AppDelegate the navigation bar color, so all the app has the same color, but i have to change the navigation bar color in a single view controller so I did it:

in the AppDelegate

```
let color = UIColor(red:0.24, green:0.72, blue:0.28, alpha:1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = color
```

and in the view controller in the viewDidLoad I have this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

in the `viewWillDissappear` this:

```
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    let color = UIColor(red:0.24, green:0.72, blue:0.28, alpha:1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = color
```

It returns the navigation bar color to the same color

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10 you can use barStyle like this:

For white bar color:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

And for black bar color:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```

BarStyle need set in ViewDidLoad for normal animation work :)